# How to write word "hashtagged" using "#" symbol? #ed, #'ed, #-ed?

Tags: suffixes, symbols

It looks like #ed would be correct way to write word "hashtagged", but this can be confused with hashtag – #ed. What would be another acceptable way to write word "hashtagged" using # symbol?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about symbols and not letters and words.

Comment: It is about word – hashtagged.

Comment: the correct way to write hashtagged is "hashtagged"

Comment: Surely the # symbol only accounts for the 'hash' in hashtagged. Therefore, it would be correct to write something like "#-tagged". However, +1 @Oldcat!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about symbols not English language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a single accepted, standard way to do things like this in English. Nor do I think there is a particularly *good* way to do this.

#ed and #'ed both look OK to me, though neither is great. *Hashtagged* is probably your best choice.

Comment: Agreed. I’d go for _#’ed_, to avoid it being interpreted as a hashtag _ed_.

Comment: Agreed, #ed and #'ed look equally horrible.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with "#ed" is that it appears to indicate the hashtag "ed". I'd never assume it meant hashtagged, and would try to interpret is as referring to editing, which is often abbreviated "ed."

If you insist on using a hashtag to do it, the only unambiguous way is "#hashtagged".

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to write word "hashtagged" using # symbol unambiguously. Then the reader would benefit by seeing a # within the word suggesting the practice to some other word that might be hash-tagged [Spell Check demands a hyphen tribute].

I would recommend the use of "ha##tagged" or "hashta##ed" as they would get accross the idea of how and where #'s could be used to mask letters while passing the word along.